# Enermax Pro87+ Gold 500W adapter?

Tags: powertools

I'm looking for an adapter for my fridge to my power supply. Is this even possible? My fridge is just an ordinary one? Could that save a few euros?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking since the Enermax Pro87 is a computer power supply so it's not clear how that is related to your refrigerator.

Comment: @Johnny:What's not clear? My frigde is about 250W/24/h it means +1000kWH/Year=300€!!!!

Comment: It's just not clear what you're asking -- do you want to power your refrigerator from your computer power supply? If so, why do you think that will change your electric bill? Usually a refrigerator will cycle on and off to keep the temperature constant, are you sure yours is using 250W 24 hours/day? 250W for 24 hours/day means around 2200KWh/year.

Comment: @Johnny:Did you downvote me because you think it's stupid question? Do you want me to explain what's an Enermax PRo87+ Gold adapter is? My fridge is an old standard fridge with ORDINARY power supply? Do you mean this?

Comment: I downvoted because it is offtopic, doesn't give any detail into what you plan to do, and though not stupid definitely uninformed. Powering it through any sort of adapter will just cost you MORE money (due to conversion loss).  If your fridge isn't energy efficient enough, buy a newer more energy efficient model.  Even if it's a 12V powered fridge, and the average current were within the supply's rating, a computer power supply probably won't handle the surge when the motor starts.

Comment: @Grant:I know that my dishwasher used 12V. SO, what about a fridge? Why buy when I have a power supply? This is stupid downvotes.

Comment: I downvoted exactly because of what I wrote in my first comment - it's not clear what you're asking. An "old standard" refrigerator typically has no power supply at all (except maybe a small one to drive control circuitry) -- the power from the wall outlet drives the compressor directly without any power supply. Even if you have a newer thermoelectric refrigerator, it's unlikely that using a computer power supply (even an 87% efficient one) to run it will save  significant power).

Comment: @Johnny:Hmm, so it's powered directly? Withouth conversion? Interesting but it doesn't explain why you downvoted me and also 3 others? What's it's unclear?

Comment: I originally downvoted you because it wasn't clear what you were asking, but now that it's more clear that you want to power your 120AC (or 240AC) refrigerator with a computer power supply, it's [offtopic](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.  A refrigerator repair question would generally be on-topic, but making a non-standard modification to your refrigerator is not.

Comment: @Johnny: IMO, not sure what you really want? I think I wrote very cleary what my problem is?

Comment: @phpdna unless your dishwasher is in a mobile home, it almost certainly does not run on 12V. You seem to be planning on making drastic electrical changes to your fridge without a basic understanding of electricity, voltage and current.  That's a recipe for a trip to either the hospital or a morgue.  A regular fridge runs on 120V or 240V AC.  A computer power supply outputs 12V and 5V DC.  They are not in any way compatible.  There is no magic box that lowers your electric bill by running the power through it.

Comment: @Grant:You are just wrong. You can be open mind? Can you? I wrote my dishwash has a pump and a valve. And that valve is operated with 12v dc. What's this thing about electricity anyway?

Comment: @phpdna Not sure if you're a troll or just ignorant. Sure, the valve runs at 12v, with the dishwasher having its own internal conversion.  The heating element doesn't.  The feed going into the dishwasher will be regular household voltage.  Asking "What's this thing about electricity anyway" is a very clear sign that you should not be modifying electrical devices.  If you persist, at least make sure your life insurance is paid up.  Can someone close this question now?

Comment: @Grant:Can you just stop using technically words? Is this possible? Maybe you can't explain yourself what is elecricity?

Comment: @phpdna ok, without the "technically words"...phpdna plug fridge into adapter.  Fridge no work. Adapter go boom. phpdna go dead.

Comment: @Grant:Interesting, maybe you can explain me why I have 3000kw/h? And also can you make an anwser? After all you have downvoted me? What do you think am I'm feeling? THIS IS ABDUT DIY AND HOMEIMPROVEMENT?

Comment: @Phpdna - In an earlier comment, I linked to the [help page](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that describes the types of questions that are on topic for this site, your question about making a non standard modification to an otherwise functional home appliance is not on topic (since it's not a "repair" question). These comments aren't really meant to be used as "chat", so head on over to the [chat site](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement) and someone there may be able to help give guidance on the types of questions that are appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Enermax Pro87+ Gold 500W is a computer power supply.  It is designed to run a computer, has an input of 120V or 240V AC, and outputs DC at 12V, 5V, and a few other lower voltages.

A typical fridge accepts either 120V or 240V AC.

The power supply would not provide a high enough voltage to power the fridge.  Attempting to do so would probably damage the power supply, possibly catastrophically.  Even if it did, since the power supply outputs DC, and the motor expects AC, the compressor won't start.

There may be some low voltage elements inside the fridge, like control boards or LED lighting.  These are handled by a built in voltage regulator.  Even if they aren't the most efficient, they are small enough to fit inside the fridge, and make up only a tiny percentage of the fridge's power draw.  So little that they are considered negligible.

Attempting to modify the power supply of any device without any understanding of safety around electronics, how voltage and current work, and the difference between AC and DC is likely to cause damage to yourself, your property or others.

Even if you were looking at something like an AC inverter which could power your fridge, it wouldn't save you any money.  The fridge is still going to draw the same amount of power.  And because you've added one or more extra conversions (which are not 100% efficient, so draw more power) you'd actually ADD to your electric bill.

**TL;DR Don't mess around with electricity.  If you need a more efficient fridge, buy one.**

Comment: Just funny that you downvoted me and and wrote an anwser. I think the best answer if from @Johny. I don't think it's impossible but may not find this site and/or user or time.